# Use grep to find errors in log and error origin

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a installation log and I'm greping for errors to another file. To do so, I use the following line of code:

`grep -w --ignore-case 'not found\|error\|unable' $DIR/.install.log | grep -vi inflating | grep -vi creating | sort | uniq -c | sort -r >> $DIR/.error.log`  where $DIR is my current working directory.

The problem is that, using this method, I can't discover where the error came from. Example of installation log:

```
[+]Metasploit
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process
rm: cannot remove 'metasploit*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process
[+] Burp Suite
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
This will install Burp Suite Community Edition on your computer.
OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]
Click Next to continue, or Cancel to exit Setup.
Select the folder where you would like Burp Suite Community Edition to be
installed, then click Next.
Where should Burp Suite Community Edition be installed?
[/opt/BurpSuiteCommunity]
./script.sh: line 512: pip3: command not found
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
./script.sh: line 514: pipx: command not found
mv: cannot stat '/root/.local/bin/cme': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/root/.local/bin/cmedb': No such file or directory
[+] crackmapexec
mv: cannot stat '/root/.local/bin/crackmapexec': No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 521: pip: command not found
./script.sh: line 532: beef/install: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 538: ./config/setup.sh: No such file or directory
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=pt_PT.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor             (800F82),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 10122922 bytes (9886 KiB)
```

With this, I want to be able to somehow grep the "unable" and then grep the previous `[+] Hallo?` so that the error.log looks like

```
[+] metasploit
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process
rm: cannot remove 'metasploit*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process
[+] Burp Suite
./script.sh: line 512: pip3: command not found
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
./script.sh: line 514: pipx: command not found
mv: cannot stat '/root/.local/bin/cme': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/root/.local/bin/cmedb': No such file or directory
[+] crackmapexec
mv: cannot stat '/root/.local/bin/crackmapexec': No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 521: pip: command not found
./script.sh: line 532: beef/install: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 538: ./config/setup.sh: No such file or directory
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I hope my question was somewhat understandable... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add multiple examples and your desired output to your question.

Comment: Fix the first `grep`:  if you give `$DIR/.install.log` as file name for the grep command, you don't have to prepend `cat $DIR/.install.log |` to it.